# Networking problem with CentOS on VirtualBox. It works when IP address starts with 192.168. but does not when it starts with 10.2

Tags: linux, centos, networking

My host operating system is Windows, and I installed CentOS on VirtualBox. The network of CentOS works fine when the IP address starts with 192.168, but today I started CentOS (on VirtualBox) on my university wi-fi, where ip-address starts with 10.2, and the network does not work.

When I execute the command "ifconfig", for enp0s3, it shows just inet6 (ip6 address), not for inet.

Trying to ping 8.8.8.8 displays "connect: Network is unreachable"
Wifi device is managed by CenOS VM.

I use Bridged Adapter. WiFi device is managed directly by CentOS VM

Comment: What network interface type (NAT or Bridge) did you create inside VirtualBox for your CentOS virtual machine? Please [edit your question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/738875/edit) to add this information as if you'd provided it originally. (I can then delete this comment.)

Comment: Is the WiFi device managed by Windows or _directly_ in your CentOS VM?